# django cms apphook - no module named urls error

Tags: python, url, django-cms

I am learning django-cms. I tried to make custom plugin which was quite successful but when I tried to hook my custom made plugin to apphook, its giving me an error, saying,

> No Module named urls
>   .

I followed the tutorial which was given in django cms sites documentation, and created the cms_app.py file. Currently my application directory has all the files which is required to make a custom plugin for django cms, and an additional file of cms_app.py.

Is something wrong with setting of the url or do I need to create a new urls.py file inside my app directory?

My cms_app.py is exactly the same as given in the tutorial.

**EDIT - 1**

i have created a project called myproject using command -

> python django-admin.py startproject
>   myproject

After referring to the tutorial given for cms I created a plugin called first, using the basic command

> python manage.py startapp first

Now the plugin is working perfectly well, and the directory structure before making an attempt to the apphook was,

```
first/
    __init__.py
    cms_plugins.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Now after making an attempt to hook the app in apphook, the directory structure is:

```
first/
    __init__.py
    cms_app.py
    cms_plugins.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

My cms_app.py is as follows:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class FirstApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("First App") # give your app a name, this is required
    urls = ["first.urls"] # link your app to url configuration(s)

apphook_pool.register(FirstApp) # register your app
```

i have a urls.py file in myproject folder, and it is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myproject/', include('myproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

I have restarted the server as was mentioned in the tutorial, but no success. 
Any ideas as to what is wrong with my simple app?!

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial, or give us the structure of your folder? Without that, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are doing this tutorial:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/tutorial.html

i haven't got the latest of this project but i know you have to do something like this step:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#url-configuration

**EDIT**

you need to actually make the urls.py file under the "first" folder ... and you need a cms module with a urls.py file.

**EDIT 2**

my base folder structure look something like

```
src/
    cms/
    __ init__.py
    manage.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the urls module you specify exist and is it in your Python path? The urls you attach to apphooks must exist before you can use that apphook and the module must be importable.

Pasting your code somewhere would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird, but the error saying `'No module named ...'` usually means you have circular import, so basically you're trying to import the same module twice